# Permission denied on .bash_profile when start passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I try to start passenger standalone(4.0.20) and I get the error /root/.bash_profile: Permission denied.
I changed the permissions of .bash_profile, but didn't solve the problem. It's a Ruby on Rails application, I am using Nginx, ruby 2.0.0p247, rails 3.2.14.

Content of .bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   . ~/.bashrc
fi
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: We miss a bunch of information here: is it remote or local? Rails version? Ruby version? Which web server are you using? What commands are you calling ... Please, give us a complete overview.

Comment: When do you get that message? After which command? Are you a regular user or superuser?

Comment: I get the message when start the passenger as superuser.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem under Red Hat with SELinux installed. I found that *temporarily* disabling SELinux fixed the problem.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux-Disabling_SELinux.html

If that fixes your problem, then you should dig deeper to find out how to tweak SELinux to allow passemger to run. Do not leave SELinux disabled!